# Archdevils' names and how to summon/bind them

Tags: pathfinder-1e

What are the names of the Archdevils/Princes of Hell and what are the best classes for summoning and binding them to do my bidding in Pathfinder?

Answer (score 6):

Known archdevils

> The following archdevils are known to exist:
>
> - Barbatos, the Lord of the First, the Bearded Lord
> - Dispater, the Lord of the Second, the First King
> - Mammon, the Lord of the Third, the Argent Prince
> - Belial, the Lord of the Fourth, the Pale Kiss
> - Geryon, the Lord of the Fifth, the Serpent
> - Moloch, the Lord of the Sixth, the General of Hell
> - Baalzebul, the Lord of the Seventh, the Lord of the Flies
> - Mephistopheles, the Lord of the Eighth, the Merchant of Souls
> - Asmodeus, the Lord of the Ninth, the Prince of Darkness

Source: https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Archdevil

Their sources:

Erik Mona et al. (2008). Campaign Setting, p. 172. Paizo Publishing, LLC. ISBN 978-1-60125-112-1

James Jacobs et al. (2011). The Inner Sea World Guide, p. 230-231. Paizo Publishing, LLC. ISBN 978-1-60125-269-2

Because archdevils that rule hell are demigods with godlike powers, you can't make them do your bidding unless you are at least a demigod yourself. No class in the game can do that for you, you can only get it as a reward for an epic storyline, if your Game Master is feeling generous. By then, it will be *"congratulations, you won, game over"* situation for you anyway, so why not.

Answer (score 5):

#### Binding archdevils is impossible within Pathfinder 1E mechanics.

From *Bestiary 6*, there are eight archdevils with creature statistics: [Baalzebul](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/devil/archdevil/archdevil-baalzebul/), [Barbatos](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/devil/archdevil/archdevil-barbatos/), [Belial](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/devil/archdevil/archdevil-belial/), [Dispater](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/devil/archdevil/archdevil-dispater/), [Geryon](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/devil/archdevil/archdevil-geryon/), [Mammon](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/devil/archdevil/archdevil-mammon/), [Mephistopheles](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/devil/archdevil/archdevil-mephistopheles/), and [Moloch](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/devil/archdevil/archdevil-moloch/).  There are other archdevils such as [Asmodeus](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Asmodeus), but they are too powerful to have stat blocks.

According to the rules for [binding outsiders](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/variant-magic-rules/binding-outsiders/), you must first call the creature. The most powerful magical options are the spells [*Greater planar binding*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Magic/all-spells/p/planar-binding/#Planar_Binding_Greater) and [*Gate*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Magic/all-spells/g/gate).

With *Greater planar binding*, a spellcaster can call an outsider up to 18 hit dice. A [darkfire adept](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/other-paizo/c-d/darkfire-adept/) with [Augment Calling](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/augment-calling/) and a [caller's feather](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/c-d/caller-s-feather/) can raise this limit to 24 HD, but that's still insufficient to call Barbatos, who has the least (31) HD among the archdevils.

By comparison, *Gate* can call an archdevil to your plane, if they choose to accept the invitation.

> Deities and unique beings are under no compulsion to come through the gate, although they may choose to do so of their own accord.

If you cast *Gate* and an archdevil willingly enters, you still can't bind them.

> A creature with more HD than your caster level can’t be controlled. Deities and unique beings cannot be controlled in any event.

Technically, it is possible for a character to achieve a sufficiently caster level to bind a 31+ HD outsider. For example, [Cthulhu](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/aberrations/great-old-ones/great-old-one-cthulhu) with an [orange prism ioun stone](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/h-l/ioun-stones/orange-prism-ioun-stone/) (or a spellcasting monster with access to prestige class levels) can cast *Gate* with caster level 31.  However, archdevils are likely considered "unique beings", and cannot reliably be bound via *Gate* anyway.